# Cassandra upgarde from 3.0.9 to 3.11.4 causes "IncomingTcpConnection.java:103 - UnknownColumnFamilyException reading from socket...."

Tags: cassandra

I have 4 nodes Cassandra cluster on AWS ec2.

OS: Ubuntu
Cassandra: 3.0.9

I took one node out and rebuild it with AWS Linux and Cassandra 3.11.4 when put back during the bootstrap I have got a warning and I tried pretty much everything what I new but can not fix it:

WARN  [MessagingService-Incoming-/xx.xx.xx.xx] 2019-10-01 23:49:05,221 IncomingTcpConnection.java:103 - UnknownColumnFamilyException reading from socket; closing
org.apache.cassandra.db.UnknownColumnFamilyException: Couldn't find table for cfId f40bb0a0-a2fa-11e7-bbba-a77efb2de499. If a table was just created, this is likely due to the schema not being fully propagated.  Please wait for schema agreement on table creation.
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData$Serializer.deserialize(CFMetaData.java:1517) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadCommand$Serializer.deserialize(ReadCommand.java:758) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadCommand$Serializer.deserialize(ReadCommand.java:697) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.ForwardingVersionedSerializer.deserialize(ForwardingVersionedSerializer.java:50) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageIn.read(MessageIn.java:123) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.receiveMessage(IncomingTcpConnection.java:192) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.receiveMessages(IncomingTcpConnection.java:180) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.run(IncomingTcpConnection.java:94) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]

Any ideas how to fix it? Is it even possible to upgrade Cassnadra from 3.0.9 to 3.11.4?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, it is possible to upgrade from Cassandra 3.0.* to the latest version (3.11.4). Did you run `nodetool upgradesstables` ? you can get more information for that option in https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/tools/nodetool/toolsUpgradeSstables.html

Comment: You did a bootstrap of the new node, or you did the upgrade of that node?

Answer (score 0):

I think Alex asked the correct question based off of your posting - I thought I read in the past that you can't/shouldn't bootstrap different versions, which is what it sounds like you did (e.g. adding a node with a different version number than the cluster currently supports/runs). You can certainly upgrade an existing cluster from 3.09 to 3.11, but these versions do have different sstable internal structures (e.g. the data is stored/saved differently). Because of that, you need to migrate to the new format after upgrading by running "nodetool upgradesstables", which was mentioned by Carlos.

Answer (score 0):

On the node with 3.11.4 add the `-Dcassandra.force_3_0_protocol_version=true` to the `conf/jvm.options` file.  After you upgrade all nodes to 3.11, remove that flag. See [3.11.0 release notes](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11/NEWS.txt#L182) for more details.

But I would recommend to bootstrap a new node to 3.0.9, wait until it joins the cluster, and then upgrade nodes one by one, without making any changes in schema and/or topology.

Comment: Thanks all, special thank you to Alex. After adding "-Dcassandra.force_3_0_protocol_version=true" in jvm.options the problem was gone. I am just wondering should I run nodetool upgradesstables?

Comment: After you upgrade everything to 3.11.4, but that could happen after upgrade. But if you upgraded from 2.x, then I would recommend to run it before upgrading to 3.11.4