# Cassandra 3.0 one node is not getting sync with other 2 nodes in 3 node cluster

Tags: cassandra

WARN  [GossipStage:1] 2020-03-25 10:34:52,849 Gossiper.java:1161 - received an invalid gossip generation for peer /10.x.x.x; local time = 1585157692, received generation = 1695958421
WARN  [GossipStage:1] 2020-03-25 10:34:52,849 Gossiper.java:1161 - received an invalid gossip generation for peer /10.x.x.x; local time = 1585157692, received generation = 1695958421

/10.x.x.150
  generation:0
  heartbeat:0
  TOKENS: not present
/10.x.x.151
  generation:1585155568
  heartbeat:2488
  STATUS:16:NORMAL,-1019803973446170140
  LOAD:2438:2893850.0
  SCHEMA:12:2075709a-c594-36b8-8708-3de7fb58325c
  RACK:10:cassandra_rack
  RELEASE_VERSION:4:3.11.0-E000
  NET_VERSION:1:11
  RPC_READY:28:true
  TOKENS:15:
/10.x.x.149
  generation:1695958421
  heartbeat:2476
  STATUS:16:NORMAL,-1083796634382577337
  LOAD:2437:1221526.0
  SCHEMA:12:2075709a-c594-36b8-8708-3de7fb58325c
  DC:8:BVI15
  RACK:10:cassandra_rack
  RELEASE_VERSION:4:3.11.0-E000
  NET_VERSION:1:11
  RPC_READY:29:true
  TOKENS:15:

Please let me know how to resove it.

Comment: Could you update your question with more info regarding your setup and environment configuration? It's near impossible to figure out what you're doing just from logs alone

Comment: how long nodes are running?

Comment: also look to that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58193695/cassandra-upgarde-from-3-0-9-to-3-11-4-causes-incomingtcpconnection-java103

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your nodes' system clocks are in sync by installing a properly functioning ntp server on each node.  The warning you received [occurs](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/9729e3f987f1b3dea6a57cc93ba10b75930850c9/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/gms/Gossiper.java#L1330-L1334) when the generation received from another node is more than one year after the node's local time.  In the warning messages, the local generation appears to be 1585157692, which is 3/25/2020, whereas the generation received from the other node is 1695958421, which is 9/29/2023.  The generation is initialized from the system clock when the node is started.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I saw date was fine in the system. It seemed to me there was system date change happened some point of time and after that chrony was setup tp sync the time. Now can you please let me know how can I reset the gossip number to some rational value.

Comment: You should be able to fix it by performing a rolling restart of all nodes (in some cases this may require multiple restarts). If you can afford to take all the nodes down at the same time this may work better. [See here](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001096783-Nodes-showing-DN-in-nodetool-status-with-invalid-gossip-generation-warning-in-logs) for more info.

Comment: If restarting doesn't work, another thing you could try is to run `update system.local set gossip_generation = 1585157692 where key = 'local';` on the node with the bad gossip generation, then restart it.  I haven't tested this, but that is where the gossip generation is cached.  As a last resort, if you are able to remove the node from the cluster and rebootstrap it, that should fix it.

Comment: Update to system.local did not work as it seems we are in higher version Cassandra 3.0.11..We finally had to wipe out all cassandra data in the cluster and restarted. After that We restored nodetool snapshot backup which I took before the data cleanup

Answer (score 0):

Update to system.local did not work as it seems we are in higher version Cassandra 3.0.11..We finally had to wipe out all cassandra data in the cluster and restarted. After that We restored nodetool snapshot backup which I took before the data cleanup